# HTTP Status 404 Requested Resource is not available in Spring Mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm building a very simple Spring app. I am using Spring tool suite 3.6.4, Tomcat 8.0. But it is crashing when access /greeting mapping. It returns HTTP Status 404 - /FitnessTracker/greeting  Requested Resource is not available
And the app is not invoking the controller because Console is not displaying nothing with System.out.println. Please help, What I am doing wrong?

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fitnessTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitnessTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

**servlet-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.thewizardofoz.controllers"/>


     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
     p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.thewizardofoz.controllers;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller 
public class HelloController {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting")
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        System.out.println("I passed by here");
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Welcome to our world!");
        return "hello";
    }

    public HelloController() {
        System.out.println("Hello Controller loaded");
    }


}
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use @RestController instead of @Controller?

Comment: Shouldn't you access /greeting.html instead of just 'greeting' ? And what is your context path? May be this 'FitnessTracker' part in path is unnecessary?

Comment: What is the name of your project, and which url do you try to request?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mapped your servlet to handle `*.html` requests but you are trying to ask for `/FitnessTracker/greeting` which simply does not match your format

Comment: I understand your point but I tried  asterisks, /asterisks, / and it returns another error "illegal argument". on the other hand, I am doing a practice from a online course and it is exactly the same the instructor show without any error. I am frustrated with this.

Comment: Try `@RequestMapping(value="/greeting.html")` - as mapping of the servlet does not strip the ending