# Usin dynamic web project Http 404 Resource is not available but no error in console

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am building a Spring MVC app; I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.6.4 with TomCat8. When **I run the web app** and when I access to **/greeting** I got "Http Status 404 requested resource is not available" in the console I have **neither error** nor **the message I am displaying with System.out.println**.

Below my code. Please help

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>fitTracker</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>fitness</display-name>
    <servlet-name>fitness</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitness</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app
```

fitness-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.thewizardofoz.controllers.controllers"/>

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
     p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.thewizardofoz.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting")
    public String sayHello(Model model){

        System.out.println("Hello Console");
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Welcome to our world!");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>INDEX</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is hello.jsp available at path: `/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp` ?

Comment: Same as your previous question: [HTTP Status 404 Requested Resource is not available in Spring Mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054790/http-status-404-requested-resource-is-not-available-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: It is slighly different cause in the first I'm using maven archetype webapp. Here I created as a dynamic web project and later convert it to Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `<context:component-scan/>` scans the package `com.thewizardofoz.controllers.controllers`, but you Controller is in the package `com.thewizardofoz.controllers`

Change it to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.thewizardofoz.controllers"/>
```

and it should work

Comment: What a mistake! Thank you Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Please Change the tag :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.thewizardofoz.controllers.controllers"/>
```

to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.thewizardofoz.controllers"/>
```

You can also visit this tutorial : http://www.breathejava.com/spring-framework-2/create-spring-mvc-project-with-maven-in-eclipse/.